# How to drag and drop an item between two ReactGridLayout?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, grid, resizable, react-grid-layout

I have two `ReactGridLayout` in two `Grid`. One is on the right side and another is on the left side. I want to drag and drop the right items in their `Grid` and to the left `Grid` and drag left items just to the right `Grid`. I've written the below code and it works but when I drag one item from the left `Grid` and drop it in its place (not on the right side, leave it on the left side). It appears on the right side. I want to prevent it by knowing about the mouse in which `Grid` or something like this. I am appreciate if you can help me

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import RGL, { Responsive, WidthProvider } from "react-grid-layout";
import { Divider, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import ClearIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Clear';


const ReactGridLayout = WidthProvider(RGL);

export default function DynamicGrid() {

  const leftLayout = [
    { i: "0", title: "0", disable: false, x: 0, y: 0, w: 12, h: 2 },
    { i: "1", title: "1", disable: false, x: 0, y: 0, w: 12, h: 2 },
    { i: "2", title: "2", disable: false, x: 0, y: 0, w: 12, h: 2 },
    { i: "3", title: "3", disable: false, x: 0, y: 0, w: 12, h: 2 },
    { i: "4", title: "4", disable: false, x: 0, y: 0, w: 12, h: 2 }
  ];



  const [leftItems, setLeftItems] = useState(leftLayout);
  const [rightItems, setRightItems] = useState<any>([]);

  const handleLayoutChange = (layout: any, layouts: any) => {
    localStorage.setItem("grid-layout", JSON.stringify(layouts));
  };

  const handleDrag = (layout: string, oldItem: any, newItem: { i: any; x: any; y: any; w: any, h: any }) => {
    if (layout === "right") {
      setRightItems((prevItems: any) =>
        prevItems.map((item: any) =>
          item.i === newItem.i ? { ...item, w: newItem.w, h: newItem.h, x: newItem.x, y: newItem.y } : item
        )
      );
    } else {
      const myLeftItemsList = [...leftItems];
      let test = myLeftItemsList.find((item: any) => item.i == newItem.i)

      if (test) {
        test.disable = true;
        test.h = 1;
        test.w = 2;
        test.x = newItem.x;
        test.y = newItem.y;
      }
      setLeftItems(myLeftItemsList);
      setRightItems((prevState: any) => (
        [
          ...prevState,
          test,
        ]
      ));


    }
  };

  const deleteItem = (item: any) => {
    const myLeftItemsList = [...leftItems];
    let test = myLeftItemsList.find((i: any) => i.i == item.i)

    debugger
    if (test) {
      test.disable = false;
      test.w=12;
      test.h=2;
      test.x=0;
      test.y=0;
    }
    setLeftItems(myLeftItemsList);
    setRightItems(rightItems.filter((a: any) => a.i != test?.i));
  }


  return (
    <div style={{ direction: "ltr" }}>
      <Grid container item xs={12} spacing={1}>

        <Grid item xs={1}>

          <ReactGridLayout
            // {...this.props}
            rowHeight={30}
            layout={leftItems}
            cols={12}

            isDroppable={true}
            isResizable={false}
            // droppingItem={{ i: "xx", h: 50, w: 250 }}
            onDragStop={(layout, oldItem, newItem) => handleDrag("left", oldItem, newItem)}
          // onResizeStop={(layout, oldItem, newItem) => handleDrag("left", oldItem, newItem)}
          >
            {leftItems.map((itm, i) => (
              !itm.disable ?
                <div key={itm.i} data-grid={itm} className="block">

                  {itm.title}
                </div> : <></>
            ))}
          </ReactGridLayout>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          <Divider orientation="vertical" >
          </Divider>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={10}>
          <ReactGridLayout
            layout={rightItems}//{{ lg: rightItems, md: rightItems }}
            isResizable={true}
            onDragStop={(layout, oldItem, newItem) => handleDrag("right", oldItem, newItem)}
            onResizeStop={(layout, oldItem, newItem) => handleDrag("right", oldItem, newItem)}
          >
            {rightItems.map((itm: any, i: any) => (
              <div key={itm.i} data-grid={itm} className="block">
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }} onClick={() => deleteItem(itm)}>
                  <ClearIcon
                    style={{ color: "#34495E", margin: "5px", width: "15px" }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="block">
                  {itm.title}
                </div>


              </div>
            ))}

          </ReactGridLayout>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>

    );
    }
```

The last thing, I've searched a lot about finding a library and I finally found `react-grid-layout-between`. It's good but items in `dnd` library are not resizable, So it's not appropriate for me.